# Renaming jar of the same Maven project before bundling it into its war file

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-war-plugin

We've a Maven project that has `war` packaging. It has a couple of other projects as dependencies. The requirement here is that all projects added as dependencies should have a common naming convention such that they can be patched in every release. So we decided to replace the version from all such artifacts by `-1.0-SNAPSHOT`. The below code does it well for artifacts added as dependencies.
We want the classes of this project itself to be included as a jar file. So we set `archiveClasses` to `true`. Now the problem here is that the jar generated out of this has the version appended to it - `ns-commonservices-6.5.x` and `maven-dependency-plugin` is unable to rename it to `ns-commonservices-1.0-SNAPSHOT` (Hence, I've removed that code).
**Is there any way by which we can rename the jar/artifact of the same project before bundling it into its own war?**
Kindly refer the screenshot below. In this we want **ns-commonservices-6.5.x.jar** to named as **ns-commonservices-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar**.
[image]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ns.commonservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>ns-commonservices</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>6.5.x</version>
    <name>NSHub</name>
    <properties>
        <nsweb.version>6.5.x</nsweb.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <buildDirectory>${project.basedir}/target</buildDirectory>
    </properties>
    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.2.5</maven>
    </prerequisites>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ns</groupId>
            <artifactId>ns-core</artifactId>
            <version>${nsweb.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ns</groupId>
            <artifactId>ns-common</artifactId>
            <version>${nsweb.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <directory>${buildDirectory}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>Cp1252</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                    <warSourceIncludes>WEB-INF/**</warSourceIncludes>
                    <packagingExcludes>
                        WEB-INF/lib/ns-common-${nsweb.version}.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/ns-core-${nsweb.version}.jar,
                        WEB-INF/classes
                    </packagingExcludes>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.xls</include>
                                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                                <include>**/*.version</include>
                                <include>**/*.json</include>
                            </includes>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>com.ns</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ns-common</artifactId>
                            <version>${nsweb.version}</version>
                            <type>jar</type>
                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${buildDirectory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <destFileName>ns-common-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>com.ns</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ns-core</artifactId>
                            <version>${nsweb.version}</version>
                            <type>jar</type>
                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${buildDirectory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <destFileName>ns-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>nshub</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Why are names of jars inside a war important? For what are they used?

Comment: We want the patch size to be minimal. So in every release we unjar the complete war along with all its locally created dependencies. Then we derive the delta out of it by comparing it with previous release. This is all automated. Hence, we want the artifacts to have common names across releases.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#outputFileNameMapping

outputFileNameMapping parameter allows you to customise that.

Comment: I tried this option. outputFileNameMapping applies to all the artifacts contained in the war. This we don't want because all the third party jars have already been given in previous releases along with their versions. Now we don't want to rename them all and tremendously increase the patch size.

Comment: I'm curious: Why do you need the small patch size?

Comment: It's an ERP application for cargo vessels. When vessels are on voyage they use satellite link to do necessary online transactions along with application upgrade. And these internet services for them are too costly. Even an MB of data transfer makes huge difference. Hence, they want the patch size to be least.

Comment: What about putting all classes into jar projects and the war has (practically) no classes?

Comment: Putting all classes into jar projects has been done keeping in mind that installation would be one time process. And full installation is done only when the vessels are docked. This complete business scenario is a whole different story :)

Comment: Sorry, I just meant that instead of archiveClasses you could put the classes into a separate jar

Comment: no, don't be. :) It's good to have curiosity. By archiveClasses I mean the same - putting the classes into a separate jar. A separate jar of the same project is generated and bundled with its war. Please refer the attached screenshot.

Comment: Yes, but instead of archiveClasses you could move the classes to a separate module or project. This way, you don't need archiveClasses.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. However, it cannot be changed now since it's already in production. Any solution you could think of given the scenario we're in?

Comment: Write your own Maven plugin or use the Antrun plugin to rename the files before the `package` phase.

Comment: I thought as much. Antrun plugin is a possible option. I kept it as a last resort. Looks like I'll have to go with it.